# Combine hour and minutes columns in one column and get the time difference in R

Tags: r, lubridate

Dear R community members, 
I have got a 12-hour format dataset designed as follows:

```
departurehour   departureminute  arrivalhour   arrivalminute 
4                30               4             50    
9                10               9             30
8                10               8             18
```

And i want to get the following output with commute time being (in minutes format). Commute time = Arrivaltime - Departuretime.

```
Departuretime   Arrivaltime     Commutetime 
4:30            4:50               20 
9:10            9:30               20
8:10            8:18                8
```

I would greatly appreciate your timely help. 
Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2):

We can combine `departurehour` and `departureminute` to get `departuretime` and do the same for `arrivaltime`. Subtract the values from `arrivaltime` and `departuretime` using `difftime` to get time difference in minutes.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  unite(departuretime, departurehour, departureminute, sep = ":") %>%
  unite(arrivaltime, arrivalhour, arrivalminute, sep = ":") %>%
  mutate(Commutetime = as.numeric(difftime(
          as.POSIXct(sprintf("%04s", arrivaltime), format = "%H:%M"), 
          as.POSIXct(sprintf("%04s", departuretime), format = "%H:%M"), 
          units = "mins")))

#  departuretime arrivaltime Commutetime
#1          4:30        4:50          20
#2          9:10        9:30          20
#3          8:10        8:18           8
```

Answer (score 2):

With `dplyr`:

```
 df %>% 
  mutate(ArrivalTime = paste0(arrivalhour,":",arrivalminute),
          DepartTime = paste0(departurehour,":",departureminute)) %>% 
   select(ends_with("Time")) %>% 
   mutate(DepartTime = strptime(DepartTime, format="%H:%M"),
         ArrivalTime = strptime(ArrivalTime, format="%H:%M"),
          Total =difftime(ArrivalTime, DepartTime)) 
          ArrivalTime          DepartTime   Total
1 2020-04-16 04:50:00 2020-04-16 04:30:00 20 mins
2 2020-04-16 09:30:00 2020-04-16 09:10:00 20 mins
3 2020-04-16 08:18:00 2020-04-16 08:10:00  8 mins
```

**NOTE**
This needs some date component for `difftime` to work.

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(departurehour = c(4L, 9L, 8L), departureminute = c(30L, 
10L, 10L), arrivalhour = c(4L, 9L, 8L), arrivalminute = c(50L, 
30L, 18L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, .(departuretime = sprintf("%02d:%02d", departurehour,
    departureminute), arrivaltime = sprintf("%02d:%02d", arrivalhour,
       arrivalminute))][, CommuteTime := 
       as.numeric(as.ITime(arrivaltime) - as.ITime(departuretime))/60][]
#   departuretime arrivaltime CommuteTime
#1:         04:30       04:50          20
#2:         09:10       09:30          20
#3:         08:10       08:18           8
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(departurehour = c(4L, 9L, 8L), departureminute = c(30L, 
10L, 10L), arrivalhour = c(4L, 9L, 8L), arrivalminute = c(50L, 
30L, 18L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```